# SQLAlchemy: coalesce() returning first not NULL and non-empty result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, coalesce

I am querying for first non-empty username:

```
query = session.query(
    Account.id.label('acc_id'),
    Account.username.label('acc_username'),
    User.username.label('us_username'),
    User.another_username.label('also_username'),
    User.email.label('email')
).join(Account.user)
```

And afterwords I am searching for first non-empty value among `acc_username`, `us_username`, `also_username` and `email`. In order to do this I have prepared a function to create a `KeyedTuple` from found `id` and first non-empty string value:

```
for q in query.all():
    account_tuple = KeyedTuple(
        [q.acc_id, q.acc_username or q.us_username or q.also_username or q.email or ''],
        labels=_LABELS)
```

but instead I would rather use some form of `coalesce` except returning first non-empty value (in Python first `not False` value) instead of `not NULL`. Is there a *proper* way to do this? I would really appreciate keeping all this logic in query and not create another `KeyedTuple` in separate function.

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with this issue using MySQL `case` method in SQLAlchemy:

```
query = session.query(
    Account.id.label('acc_id'),
    case(
        [
            (Account.username != '', Account.username),
            (User.username != '', User.username),
            (User.another_username != '', User.another_username),
            (User.email != '', User.email)
        ],
        else_='')
    .label('username')
    .join(Account.user)
```

And although this may not be the *proper* way to achieve first nonempty string (the comparison to empty string also rejects `NULL` entries) it works well in this case and omits the creation of second `KeyedTuple`.